# Why the axes scaling is not 1:1 in this plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Consider the figure

```
fig=Parallelepiped[{0.5, -1.25, 
  10}, {{3.5, 0, 0}, {0, 2.5, 0}, {0, 0, 20}}];
```

I would like to show this figure,

```
decvol = Region[
   Style[fig, Blue, Opacity[0.2], 
    EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}]], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}, 
   Boxed -> True, Axes -> True];
```

together with this plot:

```
PlotOrigin =
  Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.05], Black, Point[{0, 0, 0}]}, Axes -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 24, Bold, Black], 
     Style["y", 24, Bold, Black], Style["z", 24, Bold, Black]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
   ViewCenter -> {0, 0, 0}, ViewPoint -> {-0.7, 0.25, -2}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 3}, 
   AxesStyle -> {Thickness[0.03]}, 
   LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, 20]}];
```

So I use

```
Show[PlotOrigin, decvol]
```

The result is

[image]

In the figure, the vertical coverage looks bigger scaling than the horizontal coverage, although in reality the horizontal size is larger - 3.5 versus 2.5, which may also be seen from the plot if rotating it. I do not understand what causes this wrong scaling - in  `PlotOrigin` I set `BoxRatios->{1,1,3}`, so the scaling should be as original.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `BoxRatios -> Automatic`?

Comment: The box xy ratios are 1:1 on my screen.  The bounding box is scaled to meet the `BoxRatios` spec.  If you want the box scaled so that unit lengths on the x and y axes to be the same length, then you'll have to pick different ratios.

Comment: `Show` uses the options from the first graphic unless overridden by explicitly specifying options in `Show`. Since you specified the `BoxRatios` in `PlotOrigin`, those `BoxRatios` carry through to `Show`. Either override them or remove the `BoxRatios` option from `PlotOrigin`.

Comment: @Syed : then it is displayed using real proportions - i.e. a very long box.

Comment: @BobHanlon : if just removing `BoxRatios` from the `PlotOrigin`, I recover the figure of a very long box independently of what I specify in the second graphic. I need a figure of a short box but with the true scaling of the transverse axes.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : thanks, it turned out that I understood the `BoxRatios` option in a wrong way.

Comment: Perhaps you want `Show[PlotOrigin, decvol, BoxRatios -> {4, 2.5, 4}, 
 AxesOrigin -> Automatic]`